# Changing Excel Cells Formatting Based On Date

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a skills matrix for employees that I wish to add a formula to in order to warn us when certain certificates for skills expire. I currently have the dates spread across a number of columns with the employee name going down the side and the skill across the top, then I just fill in the date based on which skill they have. Problem is, I want it to validate so that it will be green if the date is more than 45 days away, amber if less than 45 days away and red if expired.

So essentially, some skills are covered until 2019 and these would be green, some are covered until the end of this month so these would be amber and then we do have a few cases of certificates expiring and thus they would be red.

Can anyone assist me? Thanks in advance.

As mentioned below in the comments, I currently have a formula in place that is presenting all of the highlighted cells as expired, i.e. red. This is the case with only one or two of the cells though in actuality, not all of them. I have selected the cells and added these two rules.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you've worked out.

Comment: I've added a =today() cell to reference and then have a few cells split across different rows and columns that I apply conditional formatting to. So essentially, when I view the rules, it is as follows (specifically on I8):

Cell Value > N($A$47) > $I$8
Cell Value < N($A$47) < $I$8

A47 is of course the date that I added the today() function to and then I've set each of those colours to be red and green but nothing seems to be happening through the conditional formatting even though I have cells it would apply to.

Comment: You can't use conditions `a > b > c`. You have to split these in `AND(a > b, b > c)`.

Comment: So I have started to conditional format each necessary cell separately, and I have these two rules in place: 

=" =($A$47-$I$8)<0"
=" =($A$47-$I$8)>0"

A47 is again today's date and then I8 is the cell where I reference a date in the future. I am literally trying to use the cells as numbers at this point and just take it away from today's date and if its in the minus, it's good and if its in the plus, it's bad. Yet still, nothing changes in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to format the cells separately, you can mark the complete range and apply the conditional format all in one.

These three rules should work for your problem:

`$I$8 < $A$47` Cell format fill red
`=AND($I$8 - $A$47 <= 45, $I$8 - $A$47 > 0)` Cell format fill amber
`$I$8 - $A$47 > 45` Cell format fill green

Comment: How do I ensure that it references all of the other cells though? In the solution provided, wouldn't that only be checking I8 against A47?

Comment: I don't know, how Excel manage this, but it works. I tried it out, marked a range and entered the formulas with one example cell address. Excel then calculates the address of each cell correctly.

Comment: They're all coming up Amber if I use the mass selection method.

Comment: Strange. I got red, amber green. Could you check the conditional format with only one cell, where you test the tree possiblitites?

Comment: Nope, still getting everything changing to one solid colour instead of applying the rules, it seems. It works if I literally just set up one cell and change the date accordingly, however.